# Does $n$ and $(n-1)/2$ being strong probable primes imply $n$ prime?

Tags: nt.number-theory, prime-numbers

A strong probable prime is a positive integer $m$ either $2$, or such that when expressed as $m=d\;2^s$ with $d$ odd, it holds that $2^d\equiv1\pmod m$, or that $2^{(d\;2^r)}\equiv-1\pmod m$ for some $r$ with $0\le r<s$. All primes are strong probable primes, and most strong probable primes are prime; exceptions are the strong pseudoprimes (OEIS [A001262](https://oeis.org/A001262)).

If both $n$ and $m=(n-1)/2$ are strong probable primes, does it follow that $n$ is prime?

---

If $m$ is a strong probable prime other than $2$, then $m$ is odd, and $n=2m+1$ being a strong probable prime reduces to $2^m\equiv\pm1\pmod n$.

If  $m=(n-1)/2$ is prime and $2^m\equiv\pm1\pmod n$, then $n$ is prime ([proof by Fedor Petrov](https://mathoverflow.net/a/295517/122065)).

Therefore, any exception $n$ to the question's proposition has $(n-1)/2$ among strong pseudoprimes (OEIS [A001262](https://oeis.org/A001262)).

The [table of Fermat pseudoprimes below $2^{64}$](http://www.cecm.sfu.ca/Pseudoprimes/index-2-to-64.html) compiled by Jan Feitsma and William Galway allows to quickly establish that the proposition holds for the $542622$ values of $n$ less than $2^{65}$ such that $n$ and $(n-1)/2$ are strong probable primes, but $(n-1)/2$ is composite (OEIS [A301643](https://oeis.org/A301643), currently under review).

<sup>It is not surprising that the above is inconclusive: strong pseudoprimes  (OEIS [A001262](https://oeis.org/A001262)) are a small subset of Euler pseudoprimes (OEIS [A006970](https://oeis.org/A006970)), and a similar exploration for the $950622$ values of $n$ less than $2^{65}$ such that $n$ and $(n-1)/2$ pass the Euler test, but $(n-1)/2$ is composite, shows there are only two composites $n$: $(2\cdot4^{23}+1)/3=283\cdot P_{12}$ and $(2\cdot4^{29}+1)/3=2833\cdot 37171\cdot P_{10}$.</sup>